# How to add http headers when load xml with ASP classic

Tags: xml, parsing, asp-classic, http-headers

I use MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0 with ASP classic to load and parse XML file from remote server - like:

```
Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0") 
xml.async = False
xml.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xml_src="www.demolink.com/xml/vendors"
loaded=xml.load (xml_src)
if loaded=true then
 ... parisng ...
end if
```

Now, our partners implement new security system, which require to send a HEADER elements in http request, and I just can't figure it out how to do it. They want to add in header: "apikey","123456789". If any was deal with that situation, we'll be very thankful :)

Answer (score 1):

This link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290591

Seems to suggest that this will work:

```
xml.setRequestHeader "apikey", "123456789"
```

If you can, I would recommend using a newer version of MSXML2 - I believe 6.0 is fairly common (you can specify this in your `CreateObject()` parameter).

Comment: Nope, setRequestHeader properties is for that object (neither 3.0 or 6.0) - this is a properties for MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP object. But... your link and example there give me a good idea and I will try tomorow some code, and then post here. Thank you

Comment: P.S. - when try you suggestion in my code - error is occured- unrecognized properties ot method :(

Comment: @Kul-Tigin - ASAP i will write an update. Today we shall process sum tests and i post work code here.

Comment: Sorry for long delay - i was in some troubles last months. Let me announce that your method do not work on that way. And because we have no more time, i write a wrapper on php - using curl, and then i call that wrapper from asp - in our case we have a server who run both ASP and PHP. Sad, but we have no time for more experience. Maybe in near future i'll try to write a complete code on ASP classic based on your suggestion. Thank you.